# How to determine output for this type of program in c?

Tags: c, output

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var, rar;

    scanf("%d %d", &var, &rar);
    printf("%d %d", var, rar);
}
```

If I give input as `bn nb`, output will be `-81319504 32767`. Why?

Comment: A [`scanf` documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: If you give anything but valid integers to `scanf`, scanf fails, returns the number of values it did manage to read, 0, and leave `var` and rar` in an undefined state. Always check `scanf's return code before using the values it read. Because it might not have read them.

Answer (score 1):

Run this self-explaining code with different inputs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    int var=42,rar=43;
    printf("Scanf return value, should be 2 in case of success: %d\n", scanf("%d %d",&var,&rar));
    printf("Values, 42 and 43 are inits of not successfully scanned ones: %d %d",var,rar);
}
```

For input "3 nb" you get for example:

> Scanf return value, should be 2 in case of success: 1
> Values, 42 and 43 are inits of not successfully scanned ones: 3 43

For input "bn 3" you get:

> Scanf return value, should be 2 in case of success: 0
> Values, 42 and 43 are inits of not successfully scanned ones: 42 43

Detailed information you will find in the documentation:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: I am doing this answer to have a duplicate for "I ignore scanf. How can I understand what happens?". Everybody feel free to add better answers or criticise mine.